# issue in connecting to sqlserver using jtds driver in android?

Tags: android

This is my code i am trying to connect to sqlserver 2000 using jtds1.2.5  driver but i am getting class not found exception in android

i have added the driver to the build path still it shows classnot found Exception

i added the jtds jar file to the build path as follows

projrct->properties->java buildpath->add external jar->jtds.jar

my code is

package com.sqlconnect.pack;

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver;

public class SqlconnectActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.i("Android","SQLConnection");
        Connection con=null;
        try{

           // Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            //jdbc:microsoftsqlserver
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.0.2.2:1433/Master","sa","sa");
            Log.w("Connection","open");



            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from login");
            while(rs.next()==true)
            {
                Log.i("Data",rs.getString(1));

            }
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Connecting Error"+e);


        }
    }
}
```

help me in this issue....

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be connecting to your SQL Server directly from the device. It's a big security risk.

It's better to host a web service that connects to your SQL Server and have your android device  talk to the service.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, figured that there is nothing wrong with build settings, just the application required a clean up.

Clean the build and try again.. hopefully it should work.